# Strip directory from url and redirect to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

**Intro**
I have found a few very similar questions but I am not very confident that I am able to apply them correctly because I still find htaccess very hard to understand. So here it goes:

**Goal**
I have a multilingual website with URL like this:

http://www.mywebsite.com/**nl**/some-article

I moved to a new URL structure like this:

http://**nl**.mywebsite.com/some-article

In other words I need remove /nl/ from of the url and then forward the remaining url to the domain with the nl prefix instead of www. (This is different from other suggestions that I found that keep the original directory inplace.)

**Followup question:**

I currently have about 500 redirects in .htacccess due to a changes that happened last year:

redirect 301 /nl/oldcategory/some-title /nl/newcategory/some-title

redirect 301 /nl/oldcategory/some-title2 /nl/newcategory/some-title2

redirect 301 /nl/oldcategory/some-title3 /nl/newcategory/some-title3

etc

I still need some of these redirects. Except after I implement the rule from the question above they will no longer apply. Basically I need to handle incoming url request for www.mywebsite.com/**nl**/**oldcategory**/some-title and it should be forwarded to **nl**.mywebsite.com/**newcategory**/some-title.

My idea is to keep these additional redirects (slightly modified) in the htaccess of the subdirectory. Will that work?

e.g.:

redirect 301 /oldcategory/some-title /newcategory/some-title

Comment: Can you try to be more specific/concise with your question(s)?

Comment: I am not sure how. I need two operations:
1) remove /nl/ from the url
2) redirect from www to nl
. I will do my best :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this in your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^(nl)/(.*)$ http://$1.mywebsite.com/$2 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks :). Could you modify that to be specific for "nl"? Because the English language will become www :).

Comment: Looks great. I will test it out soon! Can I also apply this to en>www? RewriteRule ^/(en)/(www)$ http://$1.mywebsite.com/$2 [L,R=301]

Comment: You can. Though keep in mind, this is a regex, you can put more complex patterns in place. eg, you can do `(nl|en)` which will match either one.

Comment: Today I tested out the final implementation and it was not working. I have rewritten the rule to: 
`RewriteRule ^(nl)/(.*)$ http://$1.pcinside.info/$2 [L,R=301]` So basically all I did was remove the first /. Thanks!